# Laptop as second monitor via VGA cable, XP+ Vista

Tags: windows-xp, windows-vista, multiple-monitors

I have host desktop PC (running Windows XP) with a TV Card. I connected it via VGA cable to a laptop that runs Vista. I'd like to extend the desktop screen to the laptop. Both computers detected the second monitor but they detect it as a secondary and are not extending display to it. (So xp shows  itself as primary display and vista is showing itself as primary display)

There were few topic about connecting computers with software Like MaxiVista or ZoneScreen via network but this is too slow to watch movies or television on my setup.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't the way the VGA ports on those two computers are suppose to work and that is where your issue is. Unfortunately both the desktop and laptop have VGA out and you can't use the laptop as a monitor like you are wanting to, not without something like the MaxiVista and ZoneSceen you mentioned. This type setup just won't work as neither video card knows how to take video in.